# OctoberCMS add custom fields in backend

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

How can I add fields in fields.yaml but prevent them to be added to any form. I want to add these fields only with the method 'formRenderField'

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you don't want a field to be added to any form, simply don't put it in the `fields.yaml` file. Do you want to display the field in the form or not?

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you want to extend them then you can directly write inside "fields.yaml" file and create different version of it and use them to render form based on conditions

```
    <?php namespace Acme\Blog\Controllers;

    class Categories extends \Backend\Classes\Controller
    {
        public $implement = ['Backend.Behaviors.FormController'];

        public $formConfig = 'form_config.yaml';
    }
```

this is normal approach

but you can put condition in constructor to change config file

```
    public __construct() {

        // if condition is true then use this config otherwise use regular one
        if(condition) {
            $this->formConfig = 'modified_form_config.yaml';
        }

    }
```

another approach is to extend forms based on conditions, like :

```
     UsersController::extendFormFields(function($form, $model, $context){

        if (!$model instanceof UserModel)
            return;

        $form->addFields([
            'store' => [
                'label'=> 'Store',
                'type'=>'relation',
                'nameFrom'=> 'name'
                ],
            ]);

    });
```

you can write this code in plugin **Boot** method

here we are adding fields when **UserController** is called and only when it tries to render **UserModel** model.

if you need some custom scenarios please describe more so we can help you in better way.